# Only displaying certain entries from a log based on id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, cancan

I have a log in my webapp where you can input hours, and when you input your hours it automatically takes the account you are logged into(built using devise and cancan), and finds what your user_id is and [tacks it on to an hour log.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9tTj.png)

Now what I cant seem to find out is how I can go about making it so that it only displays logs with your user_id. Is there a way to do this in the model or controller instead of the view?

This is the view code as of now.

```
<% @time_sheets.each do |time_sheet| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= time_sheet.user_id %></td>
    <td><%= time_sheet.day %></td>
    <td><%= time_sheet.hours_worked %></td>
    <td><%= time_sheet.minutes_worked %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', time_sheet %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_time_sheet_path(time_sheet) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', time_sheet, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

It shows the logs of everyone in the system instead of just that user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Devise gives you a helper method named `current_user`. In your controller you can filter by user ID using the `current_user.id`. Like so:

```
@time_sheets = TimeSheet.where(:user_id => current_user.id).all
```

And that will give you only the currently logged in user's time sheets.